# Question about link between uniform convergence of sequences and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to find functional series $f_n(x)$ that converges uniformly to $f(x)=0$ on some interval I where the series $\sum_{n\ge1}f_n(x)$ converges on this interval but not uniformly ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f_n$ defined on, say $(0,1)$, by
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\chi_{(0,1/n]}
$$
Clearly, $\|f_n\|= \frac{1}{n}\to 0$, hence $f_n$ is uniformly convergent. For sufficiently large $n$, we have $f_n(x)=0$, so the corresponding series converges to some $f$. But the convergence is not uniform - as the partial sums of harmonic series are unbounded, for fixed $n$ we can, by going sufficiently close to $0$, obtain arbitrarily large "tail":
$$
\|f-f_n\|\geq \left|\,f\left(1/k\right)-f_n\left(1/k\right)\right|=
\sum_{m=n+1}^k\frac{1}{m}=
H_k - H_n
$$
which is unbounded as $k\to\infty$.